# Hooking Opera Mobile for in-house application

Tags: android

We have some HTML5 games that run just awful in the standard Android browsers, the performance is extremely poor but in Opera they run great - nice frame-rate and performance all around.

Is anyone aware of a way we can embed Opera Mobile in our own app somehow? The standard browser is unacceptable.

Comment: Might I ask why this was downvoted? I see no reason for it to be. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is anyone aware of a way we can embed Opera Mobile in our own app somehow?

Only if Opera is available in library form, which it is not, AFAIK.

> The standard browser is unacceptable.

You cannot embed whatever you think "the standard browser" is into your app either. "The standard browser" is an application, not a library, and you cannot embed other applications' UI into your own.

You can embed `WebView`, and it's entirely possible that there are HTML rendering libraries for Android (e.g., Gecko from Firefox).